# Getting ALL pending tx from txPool

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, golang, txpool, performance

I'm working on top of geth in golang. My first goal would be to stream all pending transactions from the txPool.

The problem is that when I run my script, I can't manage to catch 100% of pending transactions, around 40% of the transactions parsed are not pending anymore.

Here is the script I'm using for my test:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
)

var pending = 0
var not_pending = 0

func StreamNewTxs(client *ethclient.Client, rpcClient *rpc.Client) {
    newTxsChannel := make(chan common.Hash)
    _, err := rpcClient.EthSubscribe(
            context.Background(), newTxsChannel, "newPendingTransactions", // no additional args
    )
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error while subscribing: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("\nSubscribed to mempool txs!\n")
    for {
        select {
        case transactionHash := <-newTxsChannel:
                _, is_pending, _ := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), transactionHash)
                currentTime := time.Now()
                if is_pending {
                    fmt.Println(currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"), transactionHash, "[PENDING]")
                    pending += 1
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"), transactionHash)
                    not_pending += 1
                }
        }
    }
}

func GetCurrentClient() *ethclient.Client {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("/root/blockchain/geth.ipc")
    // client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rpc.flashbots.net")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to client")
        log.Fatalln(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Successffully connected to ")
    }
    return client
}

func InitRPCClient() *rpc.Client {
    var clientValue reflect.Value
    clientValue = reflect.ValueOf(GetCurrentClient()).Elem()
    fieldStruct := clientValue.FieldByName("c")
    clientPointer := reflect.NewAt(fieldStruct.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(fieldStruct.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()
    finalClient, _ := clientPointer.Interface().(*rpc.Client)
    return finalClient
}

func handleCtrlC(c chan os.Signal) {
    startTime := time.Now()
    // Will be executed after ctrl+c
    _ = <-c
    endTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("\nSTart: ", startTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"))
    fmt.Println("End:   ", endTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"))
    fmt.Println("Pending: ", pending)
    fmt.Println("Not pending: ", not_pending)
    os.Exit(0)
}

func main() {
    // Handle ctrl c routine
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go handleCtrlC(c)
    // Get geth
    rpcClient := InitRPCClient()
    client := GetCurrentClient()
    // Stream txPool
    StreamNewTxs(client, rpcClient)
}
```

And here is how I run geth:

```
geth --datadir=/root/blockchain --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.port 8545 --http.api "eth,net,web3,txpool" --http.corsdomain '*' --http.vhosts '*' --authrpc.jwtsecret=/root/blockchain/jwt.hex --txpool.globalslots 600000 --txpool.globalqueue 300000 --cache 90000 --maxpeers 500 --maxpendpeers 500 --txpool.accountslots 200 --txpool.accountqueue 500 --txpool.pricelimit 5 --txlookuplimit 100
```

The issue doesn't seems to be the server performances:

[image]

```
Mainboard.......: X470D4U
CPU.............: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory..........: DDR4 3200MHz 64GB (2 x 32GB 3200MHz)
Disk 1..........: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB SN: S6S2NS0TB14211X
RAID............: No RAID
OS..............: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Control Panel...: No Control Panel
IPs.............: 1 Vlan IP (/30)
Bandwidth.......: 150Tb (10Gb Port)
```

I've read somewhere that the only way to get more transactions while they're pending would be to reduce server ping time, which means, I would need to run geth and my script on other location? The server is located in Europe now.

**Any idea how to reach 90%+ of pending transaction discovery?** So far my best run bring me around 60%.

Comment: I think you are getting only 60% of tx because the other 40% is sent directly to the miner without announcing them to the network. See, the automated trading is a million dollar business, smart folks won't want you to know how to make free cash by giving you the exact steps to make it, so they will send it to the private miner and the miner will mine it , then you will receive the block with these transactions already processed, so they will never be seen in txpool

Comment: @Nulik I don't think 40% of transactions bypass the mempool. Looking at candlestick data for example, I can see around 10% of tx bypass the mempool (mostly big sized trade so they dont get front runned indeed).

Comment: when a node receives a Tx from a client it adds it to its tx pool and broadcasts it to   its peer nodes, these nodes will broadcast it to its another peers and so on. if you aren't getting transactions fast enough you will have to install lots of your own nodes, and distribute them geographically (specially closer to the miner nodes), then manually connect all your own nodes using `addPeer()` function. If this setup doesn't help, then it means the unseen transactions aren't going to the network, but are sent directly to the miner

Comment: @Nulik Flashbot now accounts for 60% of the block proposed on mainnet (see https://transparency.flashbots.net/)

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth yeah, automated trading will be 95% of all traffic in coming years. currently the state of the art bots are using FPGAs to calculate the shortest path. but you will always see some clueless Python programmer trying to win big bucks with their millisecond latency code

Comment: Woops, mb, meant to tag @kmskms, as it is the data supporting your point':)